# Is there any good known file based key->value datastructure available in c++?

Tags: c++, data-structures

Is there any good file based key->value data-structure available in c++.

similar to std::map(template based) with a insert/delete/get of O(logn).

Comment: This is not a real answer to your question, so I am adding it just as a comment. Have you considered the use of a database? In particular I am thinking in sqlite as something that can be embedded in a c++ application with not too much effort.

Comment: I was kind of looking for a plain data-structure no db's if possible.

Comment: If it's going to be file-based anyway, that seems an odd requirement

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) - Standard Template Library for XXL Data Sets implements file-based containers.

It's stxxl::map is quite similar to std::map, based on [B+ tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) with an insert/delete/get of O(logn).

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [Oracle Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) it provides the underlying key, data storage mechanism that you require or as already suggested sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can add your own template mechanism to Databases like [redist](http://code.google.com/p/redis/). If you have a string-based database, you need some methods to serialize/deserialize your own objects. Perhaps Google Protocol Buffers or a custom JSON/XML exporter/importer does that for you, depends whether you just want speed or easy to use.